# Get Grandchild Records in SQL Without Using Join

Tags: sql, nested, salesforce, inner-join

I have three tables:

1. ParentAccount
2. Units
3. Invoices

A ParentAccount record can have multiple Units (i.e. Units are child records of a ParentAccount). Each Unit record can then have multiple Invoices (i.e. Invoices are child records of a Unit).

I want to write an SQL query that will return all the Invoices associated to all the Units of a specific PersonAccount. E.G. Sarah Smith is a PersonAccount. Sarah owns 2 Units. Each of those Units has 2 Invoices. I want to be able to return all those Invoices associated with the Units Sarah owns (so, those 4 invoices in the example I just gave).

The below SQL statement works fine to achieve this, but I am using a platform that does not permit the use of "Join". Is there a way to write the code below another way, potentially with nested queries? Thank you.

```
SELECT invoices.invoiceNumber 
FROM PersonAccount 
INNER JOIN units ON units.PersonID = PersonAccount.PersonID 
INNER JOIN invoices ON invoices.unitsId = units.unitsId;
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: A SQL database that doesn't permit joins? What kind of broken product is that? Or does it maybe simply choke on the old JOIN syntax and requires the archaic and ancient implicit joins in the where clause? `from personaccount, units, invoices where units.personid = personaccount.personid and ...`

Comment: Please specify the database platform you are using. Preferably as a Tag on the Question. That way you will attract more attention from the Experts.
There might be an alternative to just writing the query without joins.

Comment: Conga allows you to pull in records from Salesforce into a Word DOC; but, the queries you write are not allowed contain "JOIN". This is according to their support. When I tried, I got a "Malformed Query" error, even though the query works fine in MySQL.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify the situation: I am using Conga. Conga allows you to query records from Salesforce and present the data in Word DOC; but, the queries you write are not allowed contain "JOIN". This is according to their support. When I tried, I got a "Malformed Query" error, even though the query works fine in MySQL.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name. I think you are right. I don't have great experience with this, so could I ask for a fully developed snippet, please?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT i.invoiceNumber 
FROM invoices i
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM units u
              WHERE i.unitsId = u.unitsId AND
                    EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM PersonAccount pa
                            WHERE pa.PersonID = u.PersonID AND
                                  pa.Name = 'Sarah'
                           )
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce SOQL has "joins" but you write them bit more object-oriented way. You use dots to go "up" the relationship. Something like this

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Invoice__c
WHERE Unit__r.Account.Name = 'Sarah Smith'
```

should get you started.
This assumes

- that `Invoice__c` is a custom object (standard ones like `Account` don't have the `__c`),
- that it has a lookup (foreign key) called `Unit__c` (so most likely "relationship name", table alias for joins, was picked by admin as `Unit__r`. Could be `Parent__r` for example, you'll have to check)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, here's an example nested query.

```
SELECT invoices.invoiceNumber 
FROM PersonAccount 
WHERE  PersonAccount.invoiceNumber in (SELECT invoices.invoiceNumber 
FROM PersonAccount INNER JOIN units ON units.PersonID = PersonAccount.PersonID 
INNER JOIN invoices ON invoices.unitsId = units.unitsId)
```

Comment: You can still through UNION